# Bad spacing in the final item of the enumerate list

Tags: enumitem, setspace

This could be difficult to diagnose, but would anyone hazard a guess as to why the last item of the `enumerate` lists below might be badly spaced?

[image: See example]

[image: See example2]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, en]{StAAfterAgH} % modified report class
%!TEX root ...

% ------------------ PACKAGES CALLED -----------------
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[polish, english]{babel}
    \input{UnicodeCharactersList.tex}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, tabularx, ragged2e, tabulary,longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex, xltabular} % tables
    \usepackage{newfloat}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}} % automatic hanging indentations
    \newcounter{tablepage}
    
    \usepackage{enumitem} % listing package
    \usepackage{setspace}
        \doublespacing
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[left, modulo]{lineno}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{rotfloat, float}
    \usepackage{python, pythontex}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt}
    \graphicspath{ {./Fig/Final/} } 
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .pdf}
    \usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip, margin=5pt, font=footnotesize, labelformat=parens, labelsep=space, labelfont=sc, textfont={rm}]{caption}
    \captionsetup[figure]{%format=myformat % makes a line under the caption
    font=footnotesize} 
    \usepackage{xr}
    \usepackage{subfiles}
        \externaldocument[M-]{\subfix{main}}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage[all]{nowidow}
    \widowpenalty10000
    \clubpenalty10000

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks = true,                              
    citecolor = NavyBlue} % recolors hyperlinks
    
(...) % Bibliography control modifications
    
%Paragraph indentation
    %\setlist[itemize]{parsep=0pt}
    %\setlist[itemize]{parskip=0pt}
    %\setlist[enumerate]{parskip=0pt}
    %\setlist[enumerate]{parskip=0pt}
    \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-8ex}}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-4ex}}

\begin{document}
    
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\tableofcontents
\newpage \listoffigures
\newpage \listoftables
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*), noitemsep, nosep]
{\setstretch{1.0}
\item 15-QT3, at $\sim$450 m distance from the intrusion
\item 15-QT2, at $\sim$1210 m
\item 6-QT1, at $\sim$1405 m
\item 14-QT1, at $\sim$2105 m
\item 10-QT3, at $\sim$2440 m
}
\end{enumerate}

(...)

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), noitemsep, nosep]
{\setstretch{1.0}
\item white-grey, coarse to very coarse, tends to show cross-bedding relicts and often disseminated medium grained mafic/ferrigenous minerals (Fig. \ref{fig:HGfen2}a; \ref{fig:HGfen3}a,d).
\item mint green or blueish grey hue, massive matrix, sometimes occurring as veins in a paler yellow-red host (Fig. \ref{fig:HGfen1}b-c; \ref{fig:HGfen3}b-d) 
\item vermilion/scarlet red, massive or complexly folded with a different colour domain, occasionally slightly less competent and less dense (Fig. \ref{fig:HGfen1}a-b; \ref{fig:HGfen3}a; \ref{fig:HGfen3}c)
\item cream white to yellow, complex folding domains, attenuation of crystalline lenses picked out by light-dark gneiss-like colour contrast, resorption of clasts and heterogeneous grain size domains (Fig. \ref{fig:HGfenplasticity}a-b)
}           
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I scanned the pre-amble and the modified report class I'm using for my thesis, but cannot find much in relation to the `setspace` (used to set `\doublespacing` of the main text) package parameters that might be interfering here.
There are also `\setlength{\parindent}{2em}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}` set to control paragraph spacing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the preamble in your minimal working example?

Comment: You probably need a `\par` before the `} `

Comment: we can not run your code but the spacing seems quite likely if I guess the definitions of the commands you have used, try deleting the `{` before `\setspace` and the `}` before `\end{enumerate}`

Comment: @daleif 's suggestion has fixed it. Many thanks

Comment: @NerdOnTour as above, issue fixed, but inserted the preamble for the record